# php check if element exist through session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

How can I loop through set of session array and check if `$_session['items'][1][p_alt-variation-1]` and so on, are exist? the [p_alt-variation-{n}] elements are dynamic if certain item has these add-on variations, so it could be as much as more than 1

**print_r($_session['items'])**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [p_name] => Hovid PetSep
        [p_code] => 336910
        [p_coverImg] => 14-1460428610-ulNvG.jpg
        [p_id] => 14
        [p_price] => 24.50
        [p_qty] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [p_name] => X-Dot Motorbike Helmet G88 + Bogo Visor (Tinted)
        [p_code] => 2102649
        [p_coverImg] => 12-1460446199-wI5qx.png
        [p_id] => 12
        [p_price] => 68.00
        [p_alt-variation-1] => Red
        [p_alt-variation-2] => L
        [p_qty] => 1
    )

)
```

I want to show for user if certain item has various variations in their cart if exist, how to look for element in array if contains string like [p_alt-variation-{n}] through?

I use `foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $cart_item){ ... }` to loop all cart items to show item's info.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a regex guru, but you could just get the keys and check using `preg_grep`. If it has more than one key for that keyword, just count the results.

Here's the idea:

```
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $cart_item) { // loop the items
    $keys = array_keys($cart_item); // get the keys of the current batch
    // make the expression
    $matches = preg_grep('~^p_alt\-variation\-\d+~i', $keys); // simply just checking the key name with has a number in the end, adjust to your liking
    if(count($matches) > 1) { // if it has more than one, or just change this to how many do you want
        echo 'has more than one variation';
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use some of that keys, just use the results that was found inside `$matches`:

```
if(count($matches) > 1) {
    foreach($matches as $matched_key) {
        echo $cart_item[$matched_key];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks...but I have another question in regards on after `if(count($matches) > 1){ }`, I wanted to loop through and echo `$cart_item['p_alt-variation-{n}'], how can I do that?

Comment: @Lisa8 you can just use `foreach` again inside the `$matches`

Comment: Thank you so much, what a useful help!!

Comment: @Lisa8 sure glad this help

Answer (score 0):

The session variables are just like any other array values; you can always use isset function. Please refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php